# How do I get a value from a hash with a value as array?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have a hash:

```
a = {
  "person" => [
    {
      "age"     => ["0"],
      "details" => [
        {
          "hobby"    => ["6"],
          "interest" => ["programming"]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to get the value of the "details". The easy way to do it will be

```
a["person"].first["details"].first
```

But, it is too long and doesn't look good. Is there any other way I can do this?

Comment: the access is ok, the original hash may be improved if those arrays are not really needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your search conditions based on structure of hash, the easiest way to do it will be represent this structure in access command what you have done.

If you want several chars less,  here it is:

```
a["person"][0]["details"][0]
```

If your search conditions based on key names, you can create your own function in Hash class to search over nested hashes and do something like this:

```
a.search(:details).first
```

If you don't like square brackets, use https://github.com/intridea/hashie and access data in hash through attributes:

```
a.person.first.details.first
```

Anyway, you can do nothing, because your code looks pretty much usual for any rubyist.

Answer (score 3):

The original code of getting value from the hash looks ok for me. If you want to do something nicer it's only to modify the hash:

```
a = {"person"=>{"age"=>["0"], "details"=>{"hobby"=>["6"], "interest"=>["programming"]}}}
```

Then you can get access in better way:

```
a['person']['details'] #=> {"hobby"=>["6"], "interest"=>["programming"]}
```